# Direct3D GUI engine development

Tags: user-interface, user-controls, direct3d

I have developed direct3D video rendering library that is used for rendering video in audio/video network application. It also has simple GUI. I'm using texture with controls (draft) and ID3DXSprite interface.

What I wanna do is to extend the GUI part to make it more flexible and convenient. 'Cause when I need to add some functionality it becomes a real headache. Especially when working with sliders.

So, I'd like to know some basic concept of GUI controls development e.g. slider behavior, common events, the common GUI controls classes architecture etc. I want to do everything correct, flexible and independent. A good Direct3D GUI Engine.

What should I read? I'm ready to study even boring theory on this topics. 
Thanks in advance.

Anthony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TBH All GUIs work in much the same way.  Read through various books on programming in the GUI system of your choice.

It will be a fairly huge task.

You may want to look at [QT's lighthouse project](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/02/10/a-lighthouse-with-windows/) as this may make your life easier ...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And could you name some of those various books? Of course, I can simply "google" it but I'd like to have advise from the experienced person. Thanks.

Comment: I've found very interesting article right here - http://www.gamedev.net/reference/programming/features/gui/ Probably will help someone.